# Can't access data in ActiveHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Gem active_hash https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash to create models for simple data that I don't want to create DB tables for.

For example, I have this model setup for FieldTypes:

```
class FieldType < ActiveHash::Base
  self.data = [
      {:id => 1, :name => "text", :friendly_name => "Text"},
      {:id => 2, :name => "textarea", :friendly_ => "Text Area"},
      {:id => 3, :name => "image", :friendly_ => "Image"},
  ]
end
```

And I'm trying to list these field types for a select:

```
def field_types_for_select
  #FieldType.all.order('name asc').collect { |t| [t.friendly_name, t.name] }
  FieldType.pluck(:friendly_name, :name)
end
```

But I get an error that order, collect or pluck are not defined.

How do I access this data? This works fine on other models, just not ActiveHash ones. According to the docs the model should work the same as ActiveRecord but I don't seem to be able to access it the same. `FieldType.all` works, but other methods do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluck isn't defined on [`ActiveHash::Base`](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash/blob/master/lib/active_hash/base.rb). It is defined on [`ActiveRecord::Relation::Calculations`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L125), and it's purpose is to produce a SQL select for the columns you specify. You will not be able to get it to work with `ActiveHash`.

You can, however, define your own `pluck` on your `FieldType` model.

```
def self.pluck(*columns)
  data.map { |row| row.values_at(*columns) }
end
```

Or query the data directly:

```
FiledType.data.map { |row| row.values_at(:friendly_name, :name) }
```